# iOS: why does layoutIfNeeded call traitCollectionDidChange? (AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am confused why is his happening? If you call `layoutIfNeeded` like in this example the `traitCollectionDidChange` is called under the hood. I need some work to be done before I call `super` functions.

```
import UIKit

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        print(1)

//      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        print(2)
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        print(3)
    }
}
```

I assumed that this example will print `1, 2, 3`but it will print `1, 3, 2, 3` if I call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`. Any kind of bug or is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

Bitten by this today, what's worse is that when `traitCollectionDidChange` is called, `hasDifferentColorAppearanceComparedToTraitCollection` goes to true, and if you happened to call `layoutIfNeeded` in `traitCollectionDidChange`, that ended up with stack overflow. As far as i've tested, it only happens on iOS 13, iOS 14 does not.

```objectivec
    if ([self.traitCollection
            hasDifferentColorAppearanceComparedToTraitCollection:
                previousTraitCollection]) {
      [self updateViewsTriggingLayoutIfNeededAgain];
    }
```